# Cannot upload the distel modules to the erlang node (connection refused)

Tags: debugging, emacs, erlang, editor

I'm new to Emacs, Erlang and Distel. I want to learn how to debug while learing the Erlang itself. I tried this on two linuxes. One is Amazon EC2 linux and the other is Debian Squeeze. My Emacs is of version 23. I cloned the latest Distel from GitHub.

In both cases when I try to `C-c C-d g`, I get the following from Emacs:

`EXIT: <0.2.0> [emacs-error "(file-error \"make client process failed\" \"connection refused\" :name \"netfsm\" :buffer #<killed buffer> :host \"dombai\" :service 4369)"]`

I tried runnig all this as root. I tried switching of the firewall so that all the traffic is permitted from anywhere to anywhere. No result. I still get this.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not related to your question but emacs 23 is quite old try to get a newer version of emacs (current stable version is 24.3)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it. One thing I'missed is to launch the Erlang shell inside the Emacs. You can do it either by just launching the shell with `C-C C-l` or by compiling the module with `C-c C-k`. Compilation also opens the Erlang shell. After this I was able to upload the Distel to the node.